# what is the best use of document.getElementById("id").value

Tags: javascript

what DOM  elements is `document.getElementById("id").value` used for ?

i mean can i use it with an element like heading tags  etc

or it is used with the items have a value attribute [textboxes ] etc

and what is the difference `.innerHTML` and `.value` properties

Comment: if you want to check the value of something.

Comment: Ask **one** question per question.

Comment: @user2310289 thanks but have you read my question ?

Comment: why is my question rated negative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what DOM elements is document.getElementById("id").value used for ?

You can use `getElementById` to get a reference to **any** element that has an `id` attribute on it.

> and what is the difference .innerHTML and .value properties

They're completely unrelated. `innerHTML` is the HTML representation of the contents of the element. `value` is the value of a form control element like an `input`.

For example, suppose we have:

```
<div id="foo">Hey <strong>you</strong></div>
```

You can do this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML);
```

...which will likely give you something like this in the console:

```
Hey <STRONG>you</STRONG>
```

Note that this is not exactly the same as what was in your document; when you read the value of `innerHTML`, the browser makes a string from what's actually currently present in the DOM, using its rules for how to create that string.

You can also set it to change the contents.

In contrast, with a form control:

```
<input id="bar" type="text" value="Text field value">

console.log(document.getElementById("bar").value);
```

...which gives you

```
Text field value
```

Comment: if i do like document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML="someValue" is this gonna override the previous value or append the new value to "bar"

Comment: @Constantine: No. `input` elements have no content; see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1). If you want to set the value, set `value`.

Comment: thanks Mr T.J. Crowder it was a typo "bar" instead of "foo" and Mr FelixKling really helped understanding this .

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `value` is normally used for input/form elements. `innerHTML` is normally used for div, span, td and similar elements.

Here is a link showing the use of ID.value:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml

and

#### The getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id.

and

#### yes, you can use it with an element like heading tags etc